# Custom Authentication using Firebase results in FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_IDENTIFIER ]

Tags: java, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to setup custom authentication in my Android app using Firebase. I'm generating Json Web Token on the server and passing it to the client. So when I use the custom token on android with `signInWithCustomToken` I get this error:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_IDENTIFIER ]
          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahe.zzfc(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahb$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahm.zzfd(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahm$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahh$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
          at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

I generated the private key on the Firebase Console and I'm using a [Java JWT library](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) to generate the token on the server. All the credentials (issuer, subject, audience) are correct and if I use the incorrect ones, it throws `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException`.

So what seems to be the issue here? I've been stuck on this for a long time. Does anyone know?

*The reason I'm not using FirebaseAdminSDK is because it uses Java8 and I can't seem to comprehend how to deploy on AppEngine with Java8, so I'm using Java 7 App Engine SE.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Firebase Admin Java SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java), the issue with FirebaseAdminSDK and java8 is now fixed in version 4.0.2 - November 15, 2016:

> FIXED: This update restores Java 7 compatibilty for the Admin Java SDK.

I guess you can now use it ;)

Comment: Cheers @Nico, made my morning! :) Marking this correct coz admin sdk is the way to go till anyone in the future comes with the answer to this cryptic error.

Comment: I am glad to hear that :). I agree, the admin sdk is the way to go.